# json callback error was not called wcf jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, json, wcf, cordova

I have a WCF service:

```
[ServiceContract]

public interface IMunicipiosService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "ListaMunicipios")]

    List<ClsListaMunicipios> GetListaMunicipios();
}
```

Its return json in chrome(it is JSON or JSONP?):

```
{"GetListaMunicipiosResult":[{"MunicipioID":"1","MunicipioNome":"Florianopolis","MunicipioUf":"SC"},{"MunicipioID":"2","MunicipioNome":"Joinville","MunicipioUf":"SC"}]}
```

My JS:

```
$.ajax("http://localhost:56976/MunicipiosService.svc/ListaMunicipios", {

    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        // $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        alert('beforeSend');
    },

    complete: function () {
        // $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        alert('complete');
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},

    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('not ok 1 ' + xhr.status);
        alert('not ok 2 ' + xhr.responseText);
        alert('not ok 3 ' + thrownError);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');

    }
});
```

But I get the errors:

> not ok 1 200
>
> not ok 2 undefined
>
> not ok 3 Error jQueryXXXXXXXX was not called

Comment: Unless you're doing a cross-domain ajax request you shouldn't specify jsonp. You should update your `dataType` option to `json`

Comment: @awbergs, I change dataType: 'jsonp' to dataType: 'json' and now i get:
not ok 1 0

not ok 2 

not ok 3

Comment: When i call $.ajax(... in index.html works fine. I have no ideia why the call not work in .js file.

Comment: Are you hosting your JS file on a 'localhost' domain? Also since you aren't sending any data there isn't any reason to set the contentType in the ajax options. Also if you can post your service method impl that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're able to get the JSON response through the GET request made by Chrome, I'm assuming that you've set up your WCF Service properly.

Your only problem is that your success callback isn't firing. This happens if you are doing a cross-domain request but simply returning JSON from your WCF method. You need something to construct and stream the response back.

Instead of simply returning the `List<ClsListaMunicipios>`, consider doing this in your service method:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    string callback = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["callback"];

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(callback + "( " + new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(YourListObjectGoesHere)  + " )");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I used your AJAX call and the success callback subsequently fired.